# npm not flattening local dependencies

Tags: npm, webpack

I've got a web application `A` that uses libraries `B` and `C`, and `B` also uses `C` (same version):

```
A -> B, C
B -> C
```

Both `B` and `C` are published in the npm registry, and that's how `A` gets them. All that works fine, and `npm install` flattens things so that there's only one instance of `C` that both `A` and `B` use.

When I change `A` to use `B` as a local dependency (either with a `file:` URL or with `npm link`), the copy of `C` from `B` is visible from `A`, and webpack puts two identical copies of `C` into the output file, one used by `A` and one used by `B`. This is a problem because `A` creates an object from a class and `B` does an `instanceof` that class, which fails because the classes are from different modules. (They're considered different classes by JavaScript.)

[This npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20158) describes this problem. It's been opened for three years with no comments.

I've tried yarn, which has the same results (except all of `B` is copied instead of linked).

I've tried `npm dedupe`, which did a bunch of damage to `B`'s local tree so that it would no longer compile. (I'm using TypeScript if it makes a difference.)

Details: npm 6.13.1, webpack 4.46.0.

So:

1. Am I generally doing things right by using local `file:` URLs and/or links to develop the libraries?
2. Can I somehow force npm to not use the `node_modules` directory from `B` and instead create its own, which it would flatten?
3. Can I somehow get webpack to flatten?